# Given some $f\in C(K)$ with the supremum norm , find explicitly a $\phi \in (C(K))^{*} $ such that $|\phi| =1$ and $\phi(f)=|f|$

Tags: functional-analysis

K is compact and hausdorff

I have seen this problem in the context sequence spaces before and I remember the construction being unnatural.Not something I would come up with.I assume the same thing works.Also I don't think showing existence is hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Take $x_0$ in $K$ so that $|f(x_0)| = \sup_{x\in K} |f(x)|$. We have 
$f(x_0) = \eta \cdot |f(x_0)|$, where $|\eta| = 1$. Consider the functional 
$$g \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} \eta^{-1} \cdot g(x_0)$$

Comment: Could you explain why norm of the functional as defined above is 1?

Comment: @HRI: clearly $\|\phi\|\le 1$. But $\phi\left ( \frac{f}{\|f\|} \right )=\frac{\eta ^{-1}f(x_0)}{\|f\|}=\frac{|f(x_0)|}{\|f\|}=\frac{\sup_{x\in K} |f(x)|}{\|f\|}=\frac{\|f\|}{\|f\|}=1$

Comment: @HRI: any evaluation at a point is a functional of norm $1$.